# Unable to pass data from parent to child in angular

Tags: angular

I am new to angular, I have an array data in parent component which i am passing to child component. In child component the length of array coming as zero.

**Code**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jrkvg1-hzvbjz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstudent-dashboard%2Fcontainers%2Fstudent-dashboard%2Fstudent-dashboard.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fstudent-dashboard%2Fcomponents%2Fstudent-count%2Fstudent-count.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fstudent-dashboard%2Fstudent-dashboard.module.ts

As a expected result count should be 5 but receiving as zero.
[image]

Could anyone help me out here, not sure what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the value to the child component correctly.

Currently you have:

```html
<student-count>
  [items] = "students"
</student-count>
```

This should be:

```html
<student-count [items]="students"></student-count>
```

Properties are passed via `[]` and events/handlers use `()`. Two-way binding uses `[()]`.

Keep in mind that `@Input` only invokes change detection when the *reference* changes. So with arrays and objects, change detection won't respond if a member of the array changes, or a property on an object changes.

You have to pass an entirely new array or object to `@Input` to get change detection to work as expected.